# Need to replace a string after javascript countdown reaches 0

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to have a countdown timer with at the end (after it reaches 0) saying it "live" in the place of the 0.

this is the script i have:

```
 <div>
 <div class="container">
    <div id="progress" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>                 
</div>
```

With the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function ($) {
    var timer = null,
        startTime = null,
        progress = $("#progress").shieldProgressBar({
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            value: 10,
            layout: "circular",
            layoutOptions: {
                circular: {
                    width: 40,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    color: "#1E98E4"
                }
            },
            text: {

                enabled: true,
                template: '<span style="font-size:20px;">{0:n0}</span>" '
            },
            reversed: true
        }).swidget();

         startTime = Date.now();
                timer = setInterval(updateProgress, 100);


    function updateProgress() {
        var remaining = 10 - (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
        progress.value(remaining);
        if (remaining <= 0) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Live';
            clearInterval(timer);
        }




    }
});
```

I added this little string to replace the "0" by "live" but nothing happens at end of timer:

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'You are ready';
```

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: I don't know why your code doesn't work, but you can use `setTimeout` instead of using `setInterval` and clearing.

Comment: But what advantage does recursively using `setTimeout` until a condition is reached have over `setInterval` followed by `clearInterval` when the condition is reached?

Comment: setTimeout stops the timer. I am blocked & passed already a few hours to get it.

Comment: what happens at `progress.value(remaining);` ?

Comment: show the remaining time

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi It means you don't have to bother calling `clearInterval` and it won't stack up function calls if the users' focus leaves the page (`setInterval` pushes a function call onto the timer stack every time the interval is complete. None of those functions are popped from the stack when the page is out of focus)

Answer (score 0):

you seem to already have Jquery included in your project, jquery makes tasks like this a lot easier all you would need to do in your case is:`$(".container").html('Live!');`

NOTE: Make sure your remaining variable actually reaches 0. basically make sure your timer works. I +1 caseys suggestion to use [setTimout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="container">`

`document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Live';`

Your div's *class* is `"container"`, but you are attempting to select it by `id`. Update your selector and you should be just fine.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var timer = setInterval(updateProgress, 100);

  function updateProgress() {
    var remaining = 10 - (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
    if (remaining <= 0) {
      $('.container').html('Live');
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Ok damn using an 'id' call instead of an 'class'. It worked by replacing the 'class' by 'id'.  Thanks alot!

Comment: That should also work! Note that if you have CSS in your project, it may expect an element with the class `container`. Bootstrap in particular uses that pattern often. If you don't have CSS, though, that should work just fine.

Comment: that true. But it doesn't affect it. Althought gonna re-use the 'class' as security.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the container div with: getElementById, but it have only class attribute, try this:

document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].innerHTML = 'Live';

or

change your div to `<div id="container" />`

Comment: Yep just did it and it works. Don't remember why i used a class... thank you